# How do I access a UICollectionViewCell object that isn't yet visible?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

My UICollectionViewCell is supposed to change its appearance when it comes into view (just a simple alpha/opacity change on one of the subviews). My code works fine when I scroll (vertically) slowly, but my attempt to access the cell (using cellForItemAt) returns nil when I scroll very quickly. Debugging + research reveals that cellForItem returns nil when the cell object isn't visible yet (even if the object is created), which is what happens when I scroll quickly.

What's the best way to to access the cell object when it's not visible yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description I'd say that the ideal way to access those cells is in function `collectionView:willDisplayCell:forItemAtIndexPath:`
That function tells you that the specified cell is just about to be displayed in the collection view.

So you can use it like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let cell = cell as? YourCell else { return }
    // change alpha etc...
}
```